# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, flask, python-3.4, flask-wtforms, python-babel

I am new to Python and Flask. I am working my way throught this tutorials: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms
Right now i am getting an error for which i can't find a fix for. I have reinstalled Python 3.4.3 and reinstalled the virtual environment, I have copyed the code directly from the tutorial to make sure i did not make a mistake while typing, still nothing works.

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

from app import views
```

views.py

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from app import app
from .forms import LoginForm

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'nickname': 'Miguel'}
    posts = [
        {
            'author': {'nickname': 'John'},
            'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!'
        },
        {
            'author': {'nickname': 'Susan'},
            'body': 'The Avengers movie was so cool!'
        }
    ]
    return render_template("index.html",
                           title='Home',
                           user=user,
                           posts=posts)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html',
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form)
```

forms.py

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class LoginForm(Form):
    openid = StringField('openid', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)
```

run.py

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

The error:

```
(flask) G:\microblog>python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "G:\microblog\app\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "G:\microblog\app\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .forms import LoginForm
  File "G:\microblog\app\forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask.ext.wtf import Form
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\flask\exthook.py", line 62, in load_module
    __import__(realname)
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .form import Form
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .i18n import translations
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\i18n.py", line 12, in <module>
    from flask_babel import get_locale
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\flask_babel\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from babel import dates, numbers, support, Locale
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\dates.py", line 28, in <module>
    from babel.util import UTC, LOCALTZ
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\util.py", line 278, in <module>
    from babel import localtime
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from babel.localtime._win32 import _get_localzone
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\_win32.py", line 18, in <module>
    tz_names = get_global('windows_zone_mapping')
  File "G:\microblog\flask\lib\site-packages\babel\core.py", line 58, in get_global
    _global_data = pickle.load(fileobj)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I am frustrated that i can't continue the tutorial, so any help is welcome.

Comment: `babel` is not support on Python 3.4, try Python 3.3 or (my recommendation) 2.7.10 instead; also no need to put `[Python][Flask]` in the title, the tagging system helps categorize posts.

Comment: I have made the change to python 2.7.10 and now everything is working.

Answer (score 2):

The old version of babel doesn't work with 3.4. Install this update instead:

pip3.4.exe install git+https://github.com/mitsuhiko/babel.git@2.0

It works with Python3.4 so you no longer need to downgrade your Python.

Answer (score 0):

Babel is not supported on Python 3.4, install Python 3.3 or 2.7.10 instead and it will work.

*- from a comment by [Burkan Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790387/burhan-khalid)*